# How do I make an animation go off once in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I've been looking up on this for hours and hours but I couldn't figure out how to fit it to my needs.

I'm trying to make it so that an animation is played at a specific X and Y location, after being triggered. (For example, an explosion animation plays after a tank is destroyed)

I have a function like this:

```
var explosion = new Image();
explosion.src = "https://i.imgur.com/gWjqlKe.png";

function animate(img, x, y, width, height, steps){
  steps = Math.floor(steps);
  context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
  context.drawImage(img, width * step, 0, width, height);
  step += .3;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate(img, x, y, width, height, steps));
}
```

And then when I needed to call it, I did:

```
animate(explosions, tank.x, tank.y, 100, 100, 10);
```

But nothing happens when I destroy a tank.

I based my code off of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yna816VY8rg

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much!

EDIT:

I'm trying out setInterval now, but it still doesn't work...

```
var explosion = new Image();
explosion.src = "https://i.imgur.com/gWjqlKe.png";


// Animation Functions

function animate(img, x, y, width, height, endframe){
  var frame = 0;
  frame = setInterval(animation(frame, img, x, y, width, height), 1000);
  if (frame >= endframe){
    clearInterval(frame)
  }

}

function animation(frame, img, x, y, width, height){
  ctx = gameArea.context;
  ctx.drawImage(img, x * frame, y, width, height);
  frame ++;
  return frame;
```

EDIT 2:

I realized from  my Reddit that I made a mistake in the requestAnimationFrame and setInterval, so I edited again but it still does not work:

```
function animate(img, x, y, width, height, endframe){
  var frame = 0;
  frame = setInterval(function() {
    animation(frame, img, x, y, width, height);
  }, 1000);
  if (frame >= endframe){
    clearInterval(frame)
  }

}

function animation(frame, img, x, y, width, height){
  ctx = gameArea.context;
  ctx.drawImage(img, x * frame, y, width, height);
  frame ++;
  return frame;

}

function animate(img, x, y, width, height, steps){
  steps = Math.floor(steps);
  context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
  context.drawImage(img, width * step, 0, width, height);
  step += .3;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate(img, x, y, width, height, steps));
}
```

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame(animate(img, x, y, width, height, steps));` doesn't make sense: it calls the `animate()` function first, then calls `requestAnimationFrame()` with the value `animate()` returns (`undefined`). Also, if creating a game where presumably multiple things are being animated simultaneously, you don't want to be using `requestAnimationFrame()` or `setInterval()` separately for each object being animated, you want to code a single "game loop" (google it) using `requestAnimationFrame()` or `setTimeout()`, and then on each frame update whatever objects need updating/painting.

Answer (score 1):

### One main loop to rule them all.

Using event timers to start animation loops via requestAnimationFrame will cause you all sort of problems. `requestAnimationFrame` will fire for the next frame in the same order as the last frame. If your timeout gets in during the frame before any other frames it will be the first function to draw to the canvas, then the other frames will draw over the top.

As [nnnnnnn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615754/nnnnnn) pointed out in the comment use only one game loop and save yourself a lot of unneeded complexity in getting the order of renders correct.

#### `requestAnimationFrame` time argument

`requestAnimationFrame` provides a timer in as the first argument. This timer is the current frame time, not the actual time. This lets you compute times from the V sync (display refresh)

#### Example of timing and animation

To animate some FX for a set time record the start time, set a duration and animate to the time given in the frames argument.

The example shows a simple explode timer used in a main loop. You begin the timer when needed supplying the current frame time. While it is active you give it the current time, It updates its own relative time, and when done the `active` flag is set to `false`. You render your animation via its `current` time which will be from 0 to length

This is only one animation, you would use a stack of such time objects, adding to the stack for each timed animation.

```
const explode = {
   start : null,
   length : 1000,
   current : 0,
   active : false,
   begin(time,length = this.length){
       this.start = time;
       this.length = length;
       this.active = true;
       this.current = 0;
   },
   getCurrent(time){
       this.current = time - this.start;
       this.active =  this.current <= this.length;
       return this.current;
   }
}

var tankDead = false;     
function mainLoop(time){ // time is supplied by requestAnimationFrame
   if(tankDead ) {   
      tankDead = false;
      explode.begin(time,2000); // two seconds
   }

   if(explode.active){
       explode.getCurrent(time);
       if(explode.active){
           // explode.current is the time
           // draw the animation at time explode.current
       } else {
           // explosion is complete
       }


   }
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}      
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

#### Timing animations via a tick.

Though I prefer the fixed frame rate method and just count down a tick timer

```
var tankDead = false;     
var explodeTick = 0;
function mainLoop(time){ // time is supplied by requestAnimationFrame
   if(tankDead ) {   
      tankDead = false;
      explodeTick = 60 * 2; // two seconds
   }

   if(explodeTick > 0){
       explodeTick -= 1;
       // draw the animation at time explosion
   }
   requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}      
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

Much simpler to manage, and nobody will notice if you drop a frame or two and it takes a fraction of a second longer.